# IOS: Storyboard showing UIButton in Different place when selected

Tags: ios, storyboard

Something weird has happened to my storyboard. Some buttons and labels are not showing where they should based on their coordinates and also how they appear when the app runs.

In the following picture, when selected the outlines of the elements are appearing above where they do in the actual storyboard.

[image]

There are no constraints and I'm not using autolayout.  The storyboard just seems to have gotten out of whack.

I have tried closing the progam and reopening and also cleaning project without success.

Thanks for any suggestions on how to get buttons/labels to appear where they should based on their x,y, width, height settings.

Comment: sometimes deleting and re-adding the elements helps

Comment: Check the source/target constraints; sometimes you need to swap them.